# Regular Expression validation for Error: a potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have a change password form and in the password field I am adding `<script>alert()` and I am getting this error:

```
A potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client
```

For this I want to add a regular expression validation, I have tried below validation but its not working:

```
[RegularExpression(@"/[^a-zA-Z0-9'_-.&#@$]*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Password")]
```

I just only want to allow user (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `'_-.&#@$`), nothing else.

If user add `<script>alert()</script>` type of value in password field then it should show a validation. I don't want to allow user to store this type of password.

Comment: As you mentioned ** I just only wants to allow user (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-.&#@$), nothing else. ** try ^[a-zA-Z0-9'.&#@$-]*$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems with the pattern:

1. You have to get *at least one* symbol: `[...]+` instead of `[...]*` (if *empty password* is OK, then `*` is correct, however)
2. You should check for *is* not *ends with*: `^[...]+$` instead of `[...]+$`
3. You want *within* range check, not *out of* range check: `[...]`, not `[^...]`
4. Finally `-` when within brackets `[...]` means *range*, e.g. `A-Z`; escape it: `[...\-...]`

Summing up

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9'_\-.&#@$]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Password")]
```

Most probably, you want to have the password being *at least* `n` characters long; in this case change `+` to `{n,}`, e.g. for typical password min length of `n == 8`:

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9'_\-.&#@$]{8,}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Password")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this pattern. Hyphen should be at end or at start.

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9'_.&#@$-]
```

OR

```
[^-a-zA-Z0-9'_.&#@$]
```

For Hyphen using using `\-` will also be fine